# Linux kernel boot: uninitialized urandom read (16 bytes read)

Tags: kernel, random

In `dmesg`, I see the following entries:

```
[    0.989416] random: systemd-tmpfile: uninitialized urandom read (16 bytes read)
[    0.989708] random: systemd-tmpfile: uninitialized urandom read (16 bytes read)
[    0.998741] random: systemd-udevd: uninitialized urandom read (16 bytes read)
[    0.999181] random: systemd-udevd: uninitialized urandom read (16 bytes read)
[    0.999285] random: systemd-udevd: uninitialized urandom read (16 bytes read)
[    1.005370] random: systemd-udevd: uninitialized urandom read (16 bytes read)
[    1.005521] random: systemd-udevd: uninitialized urandom read (16 bytes read)
[    1.005594] random: systemd-udevd: uninitialized urandom read (16 bytes read)
[    1.007063] random: systemd-udevd: uninitialized urandom read (16 bytes read)
[    1.007245] random: systemd-udevd: uninitialized urandom read (16 bytes read)
```

I'm running Manjaro Linux on an Asus E402S.

Am I right in thinking that the CSPRNG hasn't yet had enough data to properly seed?

How can I remove these messages?

Comment: It is not essential to remove all the possible warnings you could get.  If you search that string on Google, you'll find plenty of discussions on the subject and it's fairly complex stuff that you normally don't need to worry about.  I did see a kernel patch that can apparently solve it: https://patchwork.kernel.org/patch/9173499/  Think about it twice before building a custom kernel as it could break your whole installation and triple your future update efforts.

Comment: Also see [Issue 4167, systemd reads from urandom before initialization](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/4167), on the Systemd bug tracker. It appears Systemd is choosing to ignore the problem.